# using bogart on Nodester

Tags: node.js, npm, nodester

TLDR: Node app works locally, doesn't work on Nodester.com, seems to be a npm issue.

Detailed Version:

I wrote a node app with bogart and couchdb (basically following http://howtonode.org/bogart-couchdb) and it **runs fine locally**.

I installed the node extensions locally with

```
npm install bogart
npm install couchdb
```

On Nodester, i installed them via the CLI as

```
nodester npm install bogart couchdb
```

and it **returned success**.

Now i pushed my working code to the Nodester.com repo and ran into trouble, **script crashes** and the log said

```
Error: Cannot find module 'zlib'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:322:11)
at Function._load (module.js:267:25)
at require (module.js:351:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/bogart/lib/middleware.js:67:16)
at Function.<anonymous> (/node_modules/bogart/lib/middleware.js:781:15)
at /node_modules/bogart/lib/bogart.js:162:35
at Array.forEach (native)
at App.start (/node_modules/bogart/lib/bogart.js:155:21)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:80:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:407:26)
```

After that, i tried

```
nodester npm install zlib
```

and it returned

```
nodester info installing these npm packages: zlib
nodester > zlib@1.0.5 preinstall /node/app/username/repo/node_modules/zlib
nodester > node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build
nodester zlib@1.0.5 ./node_modules/zlib 
nodester Nothing to clean (project not configured)
nodester Setting srcdir to                        : /node/app/username/repo/node_modules/zlib 
nodester Setting blddir to                        : /node/app/username/repo/node_modules/zlib/build 
nodester Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
nodester Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
nodester Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
nodester Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
nodester Checking for g++                         : ok  
nodester Checking for node path                   : not found 
nodester Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr 
nodester Checking for library z                   : yes 
nodester 'configure' finished successfully (0.128s)
nodester Waf: Entering directory `/node/app/username/repo/node_modules/zlib/build'
nodester [1/2] cxx: src/node-zlib.cc -> build/default/src/node-zlib_1.o
nodester ../src/node-zlib.cc: In function 'v8::Handle<v8::Value> ZLib_deflate(const v8::Arguments&)':
nodester ../src/node-zlib.cc:82: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
nodester ../src/node-zlib.cc: In function 'v8::Handle<v8::Value> ZLib_inflate(const v8::Arguments&)':
nodester ../src/node-zlib.cc:83: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
nodester [2/2] cxx_link: build/default/src/node-zlib_1.o -> build/default/zlib_bindings.node
nodester Waf: Leaving directory `/node/app/username/repo/node_modules/zlib/build'
nodester 'build' finished successfully (0.214s)
```

Looks like it was **not completely installed**, but now, instead of a 503 due to a server crash, it seems to start. But now the script throws a

```
An error occurred.Object # has no method 'createGzip'
Stack Trace:
TypeError: Object # has no method 'createGzip' at /node_modules/bogart/lib/middleware.js:88:33 at notify (/node_modules/bogart/node_modules/promised-io/lib/promise.js:181:22) at notifyAll (/node_modules/bogart/node_modules/promised-io/lib/promise.js:164:5) at /node_modules/bogart/node_modules/promised-io/lib/promise.js:205:3 at notify (/node_modules/bogart/node_modules/promised-io/lib/promise.js:181:22) at [object Object].then (/node_modules/bogart/node_modules/promised-io/lib/promise.js:234:4) at notify (/node_modules/bogart/node_modules/promised-io/lib/promise.js:183:17) at notifyAll (/node_modules/bogart/node_modules/promised-io/lib/promise.js:164:5) at [object Object]. (/node_modules/bogart/node_modules/promised-io/lib/promise.js:211:3) at /node_modules/bogart/lib/middleware.js:347:22
```

Sorry for the walls of text, but this is kinda strange since it runs locally without any problem, the db connect and everything.

Similar issue at https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/issues/42

Any ideas?

Comment: Research: problem fixed in node 0.6.x. However, nodester is currently on 0.4.x, so i will have to sit this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the nodester devs, I can now provide an explanation why a **fix for this issue is currently unavailable**.

The **zlib** library of Node.js in versions **prior to 0.6.x** can sometimes cause issues (related to bindings) with certain node modules. This was fixed in 0.6. Similar issues arise when trying to install pdfkit on 0.4.x via npm.

However, **Nodester** currently (this is late February 2012) **runs on 0.4.9**(ish), and support for 0.6.x or higher is currently under development. This means, bogart will have to sit it out until different versions of Node.js run on Nodester.

A big shoutout to the devs of Nodester for their fast, extensive and charming support.